# Chrome broswer crashes when opening select file dialog

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, crash

When trying to upload a file in Chrome browser, the select file dialog **crashes** when I paste a **path with double quotes**; e.g. when I try to upload a photo.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: can you share a crash dump of Chrome?

Comment: How can I get that `crash dump` @magicandre1981?

Comment: Which Windows do you use? Starting with Vista Sp1 you can use the WER service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx In XP you can use ProcDump.exe from sysinternals.

Comment: I go to the `crash dump` folder on my Windows 7 PC and I see no dump file there for Chrome browser, just the other application http://i.imgur.com/glEwstS.png?1

Comment: try this .reg file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8g8gwlci8ws7rt1/WER_Chrome_full.reg . This configures Windows to create dumps of Chrome into C:\localdumps. Zip and upload this dump. After you got the dump, use this .reg file to stop dump creation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ef98u5y1dxko0k/WER_Chrome_full_uninstall.reg

Comment: have you created the dumps or was the issue fixed with an update?

Comment: Dear @magicandre1981 I haven't do such dump since I'm not comfortable with it. So sorry :(

Comment: import and import the first .reg file to generate the dumps.